# Ruby rubocops error - assignment branch condition size too high

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I've got simple method which fetch data from Jira project with assigned tasks to user which left to be done. Is there any way to downsize method below to avoid rubocop `condition size too high` error?

```
def initialize
  @project = Jira::ProjectConnection.new('project_key').call
end

def assigned_task_list
  project.issues.map do |issue|
    next unless issue.fields.dig('status', 'name') != 'Done' && !issue.fields.dig('assignee', 'name').nil?

    {
      key: issue.key,
      name: issue.fields.dig('assignee', 'name'),
      email: issue.fields.dig('assignee', 'emailAddress'),
      status: issue.fields.dig('status', 'name')
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Is  each `issue` inside a project an object? I think that is the best way to separate concerns. Inside the `Issue` class (or, maybe `Jira::Project::Issue`) add a method with `fields.dig('status', 'name') != 'Done' && !fields.dig('assignee', 'name').nil?`. You mal also get rid fo `issue.fields.dig` and add a method (or methods) so you can just use, for instance, `issue.assignee_name`.

Comment: `issues` is an method from `Jira-ruby` gem

Comment: Then each is [`Issue`](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby/blob/master/lib/jira/resource/issue.rb) is in fact an object, so you could add the method to the class. But it may be much faster to refactor your code as [spickermann recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60096787/6136634).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this?

```
def assigned_task_list
  assigned_tasks.map do |issue|
    fields = issue.fields
    {
      key: issue.key,
      name: fields.dig('assignee', 'name'),
      email: fields.dig('assignee', 'emailAddress'),
      status: fields.dig('status', 'name')
    }
  end
end

private

def assigned_tasks
  project.issues.select do |issue|
    issue.fields.dig('status', 'name') != 'Done' && 
      issue.fields.dig('assignee', 'name')
  end
end
```